# Identify duplicate tuples of different order in a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I have list of tuples called "uplink" as follows:

```
uplink is [(6, 26), (15, 26), (26, 48), (26, 65), (48, 26), (48, 92), (65, 26), (65, 92), (88, 26), (92, 48), (92, 65)]
```

I want to identify tuples that contain the same entries (not in the same order), like (48,92) and (92,48) and append one of them into a different list, downlink, for further processing. I want this duplicate to be removed from list uplink.

What I have tried is as follows:

```
        for u in uplink:
            A = u[0]
            B = u[1]
            if (A,B) == (B,A):
                downlink.append(u)
                uplink.remove(u)
```

This is not working. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this have the possibility that A, B could be equal ? My current answer fails if so, because `frozenset` will have only one element as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage from Counter and frozensets:

```
>>> x = [(6, 26), (15, 26), (26, 48), (26, 65), (48, 26), (48, 92), (65, 26), (65, 92), (88, 26), (9
2, 48), (92, 65)]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count = Counter(frozenset({first, second}) for first, second in x)
>>> count
Counter({frozenset({48, 26}): 2, frozenset({65, 26}): 2, frozenset({48, 92}): 2, frozenset({65, 92})
: 2, frozenset({26, 6}): 1, frozenset({26, 15}): 1, frozenset({88, 26}): 1})
>>> [(first, second) for (first, second), count in count.items() if count > 1]
[(48, 26), (65, 26), (48, 92), (65, 92)]
```

### Edit

Fixed one bug in the above answer, assuming that first and second items fed to frozenset can be equal (for simplicity I'm just filtering these).

```
from random import randint
import timeit
from collections import Counter

x = [(randint(1, 20), randint(1, 20)) for i in range(100)]

def frozen_set_counter():
    global x
    count = Counter(frozenset({first, second}) for first, second in x if first != second)
    return [(first, second) for (first, second), count in count.items() if count > 1]

def min_max_counter():
    global x
    count = Counter(((min(first, second), max(first, second)) for first, second in x if first != second))
    return [(first, second) for (first, second), count in count.items() if count > 1]

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: frozen_set_counter(), number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: min_max_counter(), number=10000))

0.48902677999999994
0.687653337
```

Comment: A variation is to add `(min(first, second), max(first, second))` tuples instead of a frozenset. A benefit of a tuple here is a slightly more stable ordering of the numbers in each pair, `[(26, 48), (26, 65), (48, 92), (65, 92)]`, and avoiding needing to convert back to a tuple (depending on the output needs).

Comment: Great idea :) will timeit to see which is faster.

Comment: @user2864740 the min/max was a bit slower, here's the benchmark.

Comment: @Niloct I wasn't actually expecting that, interesting! I was expecting the performance to be the same, using the tuples for the other differences and potential ease-of-use. Does this hold as N is increased significantly?